# Return Initial-state only once

Tags: c++, initialization

may you have an idea.

I want to call a discrete time function "execute". 
First call: "execute" returns an init-state
Every next call: "execute" returns a calculated value.

My idea with a "Initflag" (runtime):

```
while( true ){
  myValue = myObj.execute();
  doSomethingWith( myValue );
}

//Anywhere in a Class
public:
   float execute(){
     if( InitFlag ){
       InitFlag  = false; //now permanent set to false
       return 42;
     }
     else{
       return value = value + 42;
     }
}
private:
  bool InitFlag = true;
  float value = 0;
}
```

My Question:
Is there a way to implement the "init" to "NormalExecution" -switchin to compiletime ? Without asking a flag permanently ?

Exists a better "Keyword" / "Description" for this problem ?

Thanks for your help

```
//Bigger view

// One of my algorithm (dont take it, it´s not tested)

/// Integrator Euler-Backward 1/s Z-Transf. K*Ts*z/(z - 1) with K := slope, Ts := SampleTime
template<class T>
class IntegratorEB{//Euler Backward
public:
///CTOR
/// @brief Constructor
IntegratorEB(const T& K)
: Ts_(1.0), u_(0.0), y_(0.0), h_(K*Ts_), InitFlag_(true) {}
///END_CTOR

///ACCESS
    /// @brief copy and save input u
    void Input(const T& u){
        u_ = u;
    }

    //TODO First call should not change y_
    /// @brief calculate new output y 
    void Execute(){
        if( InitFlag ){
          y_ = y_; //or do nothing...
          InitFlag = false; 
        }
        else
          y_ = y_ + h_ * u_;  // y[k] = y[k-1] + h * u[k];
    }

    /// @brief read output, return copy
    T Output() const{
        return y_;
    }
    /// @brief read output, return reference
    const T& Output() const{
        return y_;
    }
///END_ACCESS
private:
    T Ts_;  //SampleTime
    T u_;   //Input u[k]
    T y_;   //Output y[k]
    T h_;   //Stepsize

    bool InitFlag_;

};
```

Whished use of the class

```
1.Init 
2. Loop calls any algorithmen in the same way
2.1 Input
2.2 Execute
2.3 Output
```

An example for the call with another algorithm:

```
std::cout << "Class Statespace"; //Ausgabe  
for(int t = 1; t <= 50; ++t){
    DCMotor.Input(Matrix<float, 1, 1>(u));
    DCMotor.Execute();
    y = DCMotor.Output();
    std::cout << "t = " << t << " y = " << y; //Ausgabe
}
```

My Question:
I like to handle each algorithm in the same way. First call of execute supply the Initstate. For the example on top it works(depend on the algorith-structure). For my class "IntegratorEB" not. (or just with asking a runtime-flag ?! )

Hope it will be clearly.

Comment: What is "NormalExecution"?

Comment: not clear what you mean with "compile time", if you know what is the first call, then just use two methods: `init` and `execute` or rather initalize in a constructor and forget about that init flag. Smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need this? How would calling code look like?

Comment: "NormalExecution" := the else branch

Comment: "compile time" := bad word for my intention to avoid a runtime-flag-asking, i try to give a better view in my first post. Maybe it has no solution in the way i want?!

Comment: I am still not sure what do you want to achieve - so far it looks like IntegratorEB can be called in exactly the same way as DCMotor in your example. Your Execute() method is void and does not accept any parameters and has no branching inside so there cannot really be any difference in the way you call this method. Do you want to get rid of call to Input?

Comment: "Do you want to get rid of call to Input?" No, they are seperated because "Input" and "Output" need a hard realtime in an Interrupt. The calculation "Execute" can shift some Miliseconds and has be finished before the next Interrupt comes = lesser hard realtime. Hard to descripe :(

Comment: "I am still not sure what do you want to achieve" := Im sry, dont want to waste your time.

Comment: @Oliver One thing that makes your question hard to understand is that the first `execute` returns a value but the one inside `IntegratorEB` does not. Why are they different? What do you want the first time `IntegratorEB::execute` is called?

Comment: "so far it looks like IntegratorEB can be called in exactly the same way as DCMotor in your example" := yes, i want an exactly same call for both. DCMotor.execute() supply automatically the initvalue in first call. Instance_IntegratorEB.execute(), here i need a if / else branch (not implemented yet) for the first call. Question is, can i write an if / else branch in execute that just once used, without a Flag

Comment: @4386427  thank you. I wasnt sure if it works. I thought that there is a template-magic, macro, functionpointer-change - way :P But it seems that i will asking the stupid flag, its just a bool..

Answer (score 0):

```
// All instances share the same "value"
class foo {
public:
   float execute(){
       static float value = 0;
       return value = value + 42;
    }
 };


// Each instance has a separate "value"
class bar {
public:
   bar() : value(0) {}
   float execute(){
       return value = value + 42;
    }
private:
   float value;
 };
```